# Differentiate $()=^{}$ with respect to $A$

Tags: matrix-calculus

Given column vector $x$ and matrix $A$, how can we take the derivative. of $x^{T}Ax$ with respect to $A$?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by differentiating with respect to a matrix? Is this part of another problem/concept?

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the Frobenius product by a colon and use it's cyclic property
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr}\left( A^T B C \right) 
&:= A: BC \\
&= AC^T: B
\end{align}

So,
\begin{align}
f(x) = x^T A x \equiv x: Ax.
\end{align}

Now, we can use differentials and then obtain gradient.
\begin{align}
df &= x: dAx \\
   &= xx^T:dA
\end{align}

The gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A} = xx^T.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{df}{dA}$ is going to be a matrix. The $(j,k)$-entry of $\frac{df}{dA}$ will be $\frac{df}{da_{jk}}$, where $a_{jk}$ is the $(j,k)$-entry of $A$. It follows $\frac{df}{da_{jk}}=x_jx_k$. This is because $f(A)=x^TAx=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n a_{jk}x_jx_k$. Therefore $\frac{df}{dA} = [x_jx_k]_{jk}$.